# A set theory questions regarding functions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Q: Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\mathcal{P}(A)$. Let $F: B \rightarrow B$ be the function defind by the formula $F(X)=A\setminus X$. What is $F(\{1,3\})$ ?

A:
I have no idea where to start. I assume $X$ is an arbitrary $X$. I originally tried to define the function as $F=\{(x,y) \in B \times B | y=x+2\}$ however, the function is already defined. Im also sure my original idea is something completely different than what the topic is.

I also figured to draw a "bubble" picture for sets $B \rightarrow B$ but this would be just an arrow point from 1 to 3.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: They just want you to calculate the value of $F(\{1,3\})$.  Do you know what the notation $\setminus$ means?  If so, all you need to do is compute $F(\{1,3\}) = A \setminus \{1.3\}$ i.e we just replace $X$ with $\{1,3\}$.

Comment: If $F(X)=A\setminus X$ then $F(\{1,3\})=A\setminus\{1,3\}=\{1,2,3\}\setminus\{1,3\}.$ Now can you work out what $\{1,2,3\}\setminus\{1,3\}$ is?

Comment: @RyanSullivant  i made an edit to the question.  $\{1,2,3\} \setminus \{1,3\}= 2$ but the answer can't be that easy?

Comment: @bof ^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @BigMike: No its not *that* easy, the answer is $\{2\}$! ... Sorry my bad attempt at a joke, the problem is that easy, you just forget the braces.

Comment: @RyanSullivant yes $\{2\}$ it is! Thank you. The joke was funny btw.